# Swift Programmatically zoom out of UIWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uiscrollview, ios8

I have a UISplitViewController where the DetailViewController contains a UIWebView. In the SplitViewController, I have the following line

```
self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
```

which allows me to always show the Master and Detail View in larger devices at all times. The problem I am having is when I open the UIWebView in the detail view, the WebView's content isn't scaled to fit the width of the UIWebView. I have to zoom out in order for the width to fit. I am wondering how do I zoom out automatically?

In the viewDidLoad of my WebViewController I have:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

and I see you can zoom in using webView.scrollView.zoomToRect. But it appears to me that's for zooming in. Is there a command similar to zoom out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding this in webViewDidFinishLoad method.

```
let contentSize:CGSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize
let viewSize:CGSize = self.view.bounds.size

let rw:float = viewSize.width / contentSize.width

theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw
theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw
theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw
```

Comment: Thank you. That did solve the problem. I did have to put it within if(!webView.loading) statement because the webViewDidFinishLoad is called multiple times.